# Interacting With Class Objects in Ruby

Tags: ruby

How can I interact with objects I've created based on their given attributes in Ruby?

To give some context, I'm parsing a text file that might have several hundred entries like the following:

> ASIN: B00137RNIQ
>
> -------------------------Status Info-------------------------
>   Upload created:   2010-04-09 09:33:45
>   Upload state: Imported
>   Upload state id:  3

I can parse the above with regular expressions and use the data to create new objects in a "Product" class:

```
class Product
  attr_reader :asin, :creation_date, :upload_state, :upload_state_id

  def initialize(asin, creation_date, upload_state, upload_state_id)
    @asin = asin 
    @creation_date = creation_date
    @upload_state = upload_state
    @upload_state_id = upload_state_id
  end
end
```

After parsing, the raw text from above will be stored in an object that look like this:

```
[#<Product:0x00000101006ef8 @asin="B00137RNIQ", @creation_date="2010-04-09 09:33:45  ", @upload_state="Imported  ", @upload_state_id="3">]
```

How can I then interact with the newly created class objects? For example, how might I pull all the creation dates for objects with an `upload_state_id` of 3? I get the feeling I'm going to have to write class methods, but I'm a bit stuck on where to start.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but in this case a Struct would be sufficient. The complete class can be written as:

Product = Struct.new(:asin, :creation_date, :upload_state, :upload_state_id)

Comment: I removed a few class methods and variables from the code to keep the question clutter-free. Otherwise, yes, I believe a struct would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to store the Product objects in a collection. I'll use an array

```
product_collection = []
# keep adding parse products into the collection as many as they are
product_collection << parsed_product_obj

#next select the subset where upload_state_ud = 3
state_3_products = product_collection.select{|product| product.upload_state_id == 3}
```

attr reader is a declarative way of defining properties/attributes on your product class. So you can access each value as `obj.attribute` like I have done for upload_state_id above.

[select](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003125) selects the elements in the target collection, which meet a specific criteria. Each element is assigned to product, and if the criteria evaluates to true is placed in the output collection.

Comment: Cool. I've added the `product_collection` array as a class variable and am adding each product to it during initialization. Makes perfect sense now.